# How to select the last element which is of the component's type in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, jsx, styled-components

I want to select the last element which is of my component's type.

I have a InputGroup component that has a margin of 0px.
I also have a form, which is where I use the InputGroup component multiple times.

```
<form>
    <InputGroup
        label="Email ou Usuário"
        borderColor={borderEmail}
        icon={emailIcon}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Digite seu Email"
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        value={email}
    />

    <InputGroup
        label="Senha"
        borderColor={borderSenha}
        icon={passwordIcon}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Digite sua Senha"
        onChange={e => setSenha(e.target.value)}
        value={senha}
    />

    <ButtonsContainer>
        <LoginButton type="submit">Entrar</LoginButton>

        <p>OU</p>

        <GoogleButton>
            <img src={googleLogo} alt="" />

            <p>Log In with Google</p>
        </GoogleButton>
    </ButtonsContainer>
</form>
```

My goal is to make the bottom margin of the last InputGroup to 55px, but when I use &: last-of-type the margin only appears if I remove my ButtonsContainer component.

I think it has something to do with the Container of the InputGroup being a div, and the Container of the ButtonsContainer as well, but I don't know how to solve this.

InputGroup/index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    Container,
    Label,
    ContainerInput,
    Input
} from './styles';

const InputGroup = ({
    label,
    borderColor,
    icon,
    type,
    value,
    onChange,
    placeholder,
    mask,
    maskChar,
    onKeyDown
}) => (
    <Container>
        <Label>{label}</Label>

        <ContainerInput borderColor={borderColor}>
            <img src={icon} alt="" />

            <Input
                type={type}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
            />
        </ContainerInput>
    </Container>
);

export default InputGroup;
```

InputGroup/styles.js:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;

    & + & {
        margin-top: 24px;
    }

    :last-of-type {
        margin-bottom: 55px;
    }
`;

export const Label = styled.label`
    font: normal 500 12px/16px var(--font-fourth);
`;

export const ContainerInput = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: ${({ borderColor }) => borderColor};
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: border-color 0.15s;

    :focus-within{
        border-color: #1904E5;
    }

    img{
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin: 12px 8px 12px 12px;
    }
`;

export const Input = styled.input`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border: none;
    color: #575172;
    font: normal 500 12px/16px var(--font-primary);

    :hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    ::placeholder{
        color: #575172;
        font: normal 500 12px/16px var(--font-primary);
    }
`;
```

**EDIT:**
Things like "add a container around entries" have already responded, but if I did this I would have to do the same every time I used the component, it would break the reusability of the component as I would have to do the same thing over and over again. everytime. But if there is no other way I do it, because it works too

Comment: Why not place the `InputGroup` components in a container with 55px padding bottom? Otherwise see [referring to other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components).

Comment: @DrewReese I've edited the question to make it clearer why I haven't accepted this solution yet (but it's a good solution)

Comment: Your edit comment makes no sense as the component you are using the input groups in appears to ***not*** be a reusable component. In other words, it appears to be a specialized/specific instance of a form, specifically a login form. If you want to create a "generalized" form container then take the input groups as children and render them into the container we suggest with the padding-bottom rule. Your form component then becomes a wrapper.

Comment: This form is a login page yes, but I use InputGroup everywhere in my application where I need data input, so if I use a wrapper with margin I would have to do the same on every page I use.

Comment: It's either that I don't see the issue with doing that or what the problem would/could be, or you've some unnecessary coupling of components and layout of *some* parent component. Each page's UI should be independent of any other page's UI elements. You're trying to make your `InputGroup` more than "self-aware" by trying to make it concerned with it's parent component and siblings, instead of the other way around with the parent component enforcing where it wants its children to be rendered.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. like, that would be wrong because I'm affecting the layout of every page I use this component on, so the layout depends on the component, not the other way around, so the best solution would be to actually put a <fieldset /> as a wrapper to hold everything independent?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap InputGroup components with a fieldset tag.

```
<fieldset>
  <InputGroup
    label="Email ou Usuário"
    borderColor={borderEmail}
    icon={emailIcon}
    type="email"
    placeholder="Digite seu Email"
    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
    value={email}
  />

  <InputGroup
    label="Senha"
    borderColor={borderSenha}
    icon={passwordIcon}
    type="password"
    placeholder="Digite sua Senha"
    onChange={e => setSenha(e.target.value)}
    value={senha}
  />
</fieldset>
```